# Mybatis query returning incorrect results. Possible caching issue?

Tags: java, mybatis

I have a JUnit test, which includes use of Mybatis. At the start of the test I'm retrieving a count of records in the table.

At the end of the test I expect an additional record to be present in the table, and have an assert to verify this condition. However I find that the second query returns exactly the same number of records as the first one did.

I know a new record has definitely been inserted in the table.

I thought this may be related to caching, so I tried flushing all caches associated with the session. I also tried using `setCacheEnabled(false)`, but still the same result.

Here's my code fragment -

```
@Test
public void config_0_9() {
    session.getConfiguration().setCacheEnabled(false);
    cfgMapper = session.getMapper(CfgMapper.class);
    int oldRecords = cfgMapper.countByExample(null);

    messageReprocessor.processSuspendedMessages();
    session.commit();

    int newRecords = cfgMapper.countByExample(null);
    assertTrue(newRecords == oldRecords + 1);
}
```

Comment: When you say that you are sure that the record has been inserter, you mean that you query the table using an external tool and record is there?

Comment: Correct. A query executed by external SQL client returns the expected rows.